# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder in Spring Boot test class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I am getting error - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
while injecting a value from yaml file to a variable using @value annotation. Below is my project structure -

[project_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kV73.png)

Please see attached picture for better view of project structure
MainProj
|-- subproj1
| -- src/test/java
| package - a.test : Test.java
package - a.test.commons : TestHelper.java
-- src/test/resources
| -- application.properties
pom.xml

| -- subproj2
| -- src/main/resource
| -- application-config.yaml
pom.xml

| -- subproj3              |
| -- src/main/java
| -- package - xyz : ABC.java
pom.xml

pom.xml

I am getting the error while injecting value to a variable in TestHelper.java. The value of variable is in application-config.yaml in subproj2.  Although I am able to do the same from my ABC.java class.

below is code structure of two java file in my subproj1

Class : Test.java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestHelper.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Test{
@Autowired
TestHelper th;
@Test
public void test1(){
String x = th.someMethod();
//some test
}
```

Class : TestHelper.java

```
@Component
public class TestHelper{
@Value("${com.pqr}")
     String pqr;
private  String someMethod(){
return pqr;
}
}
```

Class : ABC.java

```
@Component
public class TestHelper{
@Value("${com.pqr}")
     String pqr;
}
```

Error :

[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.541 s <<< FAILURE! - in test.Test
[ERROR] test1 on test1(test.Test)(test.Test)  Time elapsed: 0.01 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'th': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'com.pqr' in value "${com.pqr}"
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'com.pqr' in value "${com.pqr}"

Note :

1. I am able to access value com.pqr in my subproj3's ABC.java, but not in TestHelper.java in subproj1 from application-config.yam which is subproj2
2. subproj1 & subproj2 are already existing project and there is no issue in them

I am beginner in Spring, Please help me with the correct approch to access com.pqr in my subproj1

Comment: what do you have in your application.properties?

Comment: @DanielJacob application.properties have some db related information, and here I want to get value from  application-config.yaml (in subproj2)